# Conversion of ARM code into C

Tags: c, assembly, arm

Here is my assembly code for A9,

```
ldr     x1, = 0x400020                // Const value may be address also
ldr     w0, = 0x200018     // Const value may be address also 
str     w0, [x1]
```

The below one is expected output ?

```
*((u32 *)0x400020) = 0x200018;
```

When i cross checked with it by compiler it given differnet result as mov and movs insted of ldr. How to create ldr in c?

Comment: @Lundin: My comment was incorrect. I'd somehow missed the `str` at the end.

Comment: @Michael Can you please explain for the third instruction "str     w0, [x1]"

Comment: @Michael Ah, so did I. It ended up as a comment because of some edit goof-up. The question has been restored now.

Comment: @BasavarajaMS is your target hardware the Apple A9?

Answer (score 2):

> When i cross checked with it by compiler it given differnet result as mov and movs

It sounds to me like you compiled the C code with a compiler targetting AArch32, but the assembly code you've shown looks like it was written for AArch64.
Here's what I get when I compile with ARM64 GCC 5.4 and optimization level `O3` (comments added by me):

```
    mov     x0, 32            @ x0 = 0x20
    mov     w1, 24            @ w1 = 0x18
    movk    x0, 0x40, lsl 16  @ x0[31:16] = 0x40 
    movk    w1, 0x20, lsl 16  @ w1[31:16] = 0x20
    str     w1, [x0]
```

> How to create ldr in c?

I can't see any good reason why you'd want the compiler to generate an `LDR` in this case.
`LDR reg,=value` is a *pseudo-instruction* that allows you to load immediates that cannot be encoded directly in the instruction word. The assembler achieves this by placing the value (e.g. `0x200018`) in a [*literal pool*](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1359731147760.htm), and then replacing `ldr w0, =0x200018` with a PC-relative load from that literal pool (i.e. something like `ldr w0,[pc,#offset_to_value]`). Accessing memory is slow, so the compiler generated another sequence of instructions for you that achieves the same thing in a more efficient manner.

Pseudo-instructions are mainly a convenience for humans writing assembly code, making the code easier for them or their colleagues to read/write/maintain. Unlike a human being, a compiler doesn't get fatigued by repeating the same task over and over, and therefore doesn't have as much need for conveniences like that.

TL;DR: The compiler will generate what it thinks is the best (according to the current optimization level) instruction sequence. Also, that particular form of `LDR` is a pseudo-instruction, so you might not be able to get a compiler to generate it even if you disable all optimizations.